# Apache Karavan to integrate whatsapp messages

Tags: yaml, apache-camel, whatsapp, bpmn

I have generated a yaml to send message every 10 sec on whatsapp using apache karavan but where do I input the recipient phone Number? I could not find any documentation about it as well

This is my yaml:

```
route:
    id: route-408f
    nodePrefixId: route-432
    from:
      id: from-9db7
      uri: kamelet:timer-source
      parameters:
        message: huhih
        period: 100000
      steps:
        - to:
            id: to-bb44
            uri: whatsapp
            pattern: InOnly
            parameters:
              authorizationToken: >-
               ***
              phoneNumberId: '***'
              apiVersion: v18.0
              baseUri: https://graph.facebook.com
```

According to camel docs, the recipient number is provided in the header. But karavan gave no such option.